# How to add a subtitle to a slide in lyx?

Tags: beamer, lyx

How to make a subtitle in lyx, as it is shown in the picture here 'Cambodia, 2008 IPUMS, inter-province moves'?

Thank you!
[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this solution, it is an indication of a user of LyX: https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/ier/people/yerushalmi/main/computing/lyx/lyx_tricks_-_my_instructions.pdf.[image]

Comment: You may want to attribute this text to its source.

Comment: @YijiaoLiu, :)) I hope to help you and you have resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **FrameSubtitle** option. See this in effect by following these steps in LyX:

1. Menu: File -> New From Template
2. Choose “beamer-conference-ornate-20min.lyx”

It is used somewhere on the 4th slide. Alternatively, you can directly look at the online PDF from [this site](http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/Computing-HOWTO/LatexAndLyx/LyX-sweave-tutorial/beamers/beamer-1.pdf).